# How to convert numbers into strings in python? 1 -> 'one'

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x

If i want a program where I let the user input a number (e.g. 1, 13, 4354) how can i get it to print (one, thirteen, four three five four) does that make sense? if it's two digit, print it as though it's joined (thirty-one) but if it's more than 2 just print them sepretly, one the same line joined with a space, I tried to do this with a dictionary, and I think it's possible, but i can't figure out how to do it?

```
l = input('Enter the number: ')

if len(l) > 2:
    nums = {'1':'one',
            '2':'two',
            '3':'three',
            '4':'four',
            '5':'five',
            '6':'six',
            '7':'seven',
            '8':'eight',
            '9':'nine'}
elif len(l) == 2:
    tens = {'10'}


for k, v in nums.items():
    print(k, v)
```

This is obviously a wrong code, but I would like the finished result to look something like this? thanks in advance!

Comment: If your looking for arbitrary numerical input, then it becomes ginormously difficult.  You'd have to code for hundred/thousand/ten thousand/million+ (for the people who want to screw with the program).  I'd recommend iterative division/mod

Comment: If you find yourself looking at this question, consider https://github.com/jmoiron/humanize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access items from a dictionary, you can do `dictionary[key]`. The `value` is returned.

Let's say that my input is `"8"`.

You can then do `print nums[l]` (inside your conditional statement), and this will return `"eight"`.

---

Also, it's probably better if you create your dictionaries outside of your conditional structures to prevent `NameErrors` and so you can access both dictionaries anywhere.

---

If you have an input `"324"`, then you can use a combination of `str.join()` and a list comprehension:

```
l = "324"
nums = {'1':'one',
        '2':'two',
        '3':'three',
        '4':'four',
        '5':'five',
        '6':'six',
        '7':'seven',
        '8':'eight',
        '9':'nine'}

print ' '.join(nums[i] for i in l)
```

Explanation:

`[nums[i] for i in l]` is the same as:

```
returned_list = []
for number in l:
    returned_list.append(d[number])
```

`str.join()` joins every item in the list together, separated by a space. So `' '.join(['one', 'two', 'three'])` returns `'one two three'`

Comment: I know, but if I enter '324' how can I get 'three two four'?

Comment: Thank you!! Now how do I translate 22 -> 'twenty-two' instead of 'two two'? In the same code as well

Comment: @Samir I'm sorry, but I'm really not going to do your work. I've helped you for the representation bit, but now it's your turn to find that out ;)

Comment: Okaay, would I need to make an `if len(l) == 2: prints('-'join(tens[i] for i in t))` and t is the 'tens' dictionary i'l make, anymore hints? :P

Comment: @Samir Not exactly. Because then you'll get something like `"twenty-twenty"`. You might have to split the string up so you get something like "20" and "2", then access the dictionary (perhaps merge them all into one?). I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this to learn, carry on.  If you've got a plane to catch, you could try [Pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/detail/wordsToNum.py?responseToken=0a9e97d0ac9689fe94c23c3db8a2ed295).  This very exercise is covered in one of Pyparsing's [examples](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/wordsToNum.py/30133105/wordsToNum.py):